# Python StopWatch to be like the one on Android or iOS

Tags: python

Here is my origional StopWatch and it is asked to improve with further conditions:
**Add the Lap functionality to your StopWatch. Refer the stopwatch app on your iOS or Android. Also, your StopWatch should be in one of the three states:**

At initial state, the getElapsedTime method returns 0. The start method sets the start time and changes the state to running state. Other methods have no effect.

At running state, the getElapsedTime method returns the difference between current time and start time. The stop method sets the end time and changes the state to stop state. Other methods have no effect.

At stop state, the getElapsedTime method returns the difference between end time and start time. The reset method changes the state to initial state. The start method changes the state to running state, and continues the clock. Other methods have no effect.

my new code below
Any idea of improvment?

```
import time

#define
class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__StartTime = 0
        self.__EndTime = 0
        self.__Time1 = 0
        self.__Time2 = 0

    def getStartTime(self):
        return self.__StartTime
    def getEndTime(self):
        return self.__EndTime
    def getTime1(self):
        return self.__Time1
    def getTime2(self):
        return self.__Time2
    def setStartTime(self, StartTime):
        self.__StartTime = StartTime
    def setEndTime(self, EndTime):
        self.__EndTime = EndTime
    def setTime1(self, Time1):
        self.__Time1 = Time1
    def setTime2(self, Time2):
        self.__Time2 = Time2
    def start(self):
        if self.__StartTime != 0:
            self.__Time1 = time.time()
            self.__StartTime = (self.__Time1 -
                                self.__EndTime) + self.__StartTime
            self.__Time2 = self.__Time1 - (self.__EndTime -
                                   self.__Time2)
            self.__EndTime = 0
        else:
            self.__StartTime = time.time()
    def stop(self):
        self.__EndTime = time.time()
    def getElapsedTime(self):
        if self.__StartTime == 0:
            return 0
        elif self.__EndTime != 0:
            et = self.__EndTime - self.__StartTime
            return et
        else:
            self.__Time1 = time.time()
            et = self.__Time1 - self.__StartTime
            return et
    def lap(self):
        if self.__Time2 == 0:
            self.__Time1 = time.time()
            l = self.__Time1 - self.__StartTime
            self.__Time2 = self.__Time1
            return l
        else:
            self.__Time1 = time.time()
            l = self.__Time1 - self.__Time2
            self.__Time2 = self.__Time1
            return l
            
    def reset(self):
        self.__StartTime = 0
        self.__EndTime = 0
        self.__Time1 = 0
        self.__Time2 = 0


def convert(sec):
    mins = sec // 60
    sec = sec % 60
    hour =  mins // 60
    mins = mins% 60
    print('Time: %s:%s:%.2f' %(int(hour), int(mins), sec))

def main():
    s = StopWatch()
    input('Press enter to reset')
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to start')
    s.start()
    input('Press enter to elapsed')
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to lap')
    time = s.lap()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to elapsed')
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to lap')
    time = s.lap()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to stop')
    s.stop()
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to continue start')
    s.start()
    input('Press enter to lap')
    time = s.lap()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to elapsed')
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to lap')
    time = s.lap()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to elapsed')
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to reset')
    s.reset()
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to start again')
    s.start()
    input('Press enter to lap')
    time = s.lap()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to lap')
    time = s.lap()
    convert(time)
    input('Press enter to stop')
    s.stop()
    time = s.getElapsedTime()
    convert(time)
    print('End')

#get all the result from main 
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework? I'll assume you're having trouble getting started.

```
#import
import time
import random

#define
class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__startTime = time.time()
        # NEW
        self.running_state = "INITIAL"

    def getStartTime(self):
        return self.__startTime
    def getEndTime(self):
        # UPDATE RUNNING STATE - SET END TIME
        # your code here
        return self.__endTime
    def start(self):
        # UPDATE RUNNING STATE - get start time 
        # your code here
        self.__startTime = time.time()
    def stop(self):
        # CHANGE RUNNING STATE - SET END TIME
        # your code here
        self.__endTime = time.time()
    def getElapsedTime(self):
        if self.running_state === "INITIAL":
            // your code here
        else if self.running_state == "RUNNING": 
            // your code here
        else:
            // your code here
        return int(1000 * (self.__endTime - self.__startTime))

#input
def main():
    size = 1000000
    
    stopWatch = StopWatch()
    # sum is a python keyword - don't name variables after keywords
    sum = 0    
    for i in range(1, size + 1):
        # why even do this?
        # If its to pause program use time.sleep(5) where 5 will pause program for 5 seconds (or whatever value you pass in)
        sum += i 
    stopWatch.stop()
    #output
    print("The loop time is", stopWatch.getElapsedTime(), "milliseconds")   
main()
```

Comment: I updated my code. How about it this time?